# How to disable highlighting whitespace at end of each line in Textmate 2?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

In Textmate 2 (I currently have version 2.0 beta 6), I notice that the whitespace at end of each line is always highlighted. See screenshot below (the red bands are highlighted whitespaces).

[image]

How do I disable this? I have looked in the preferences, but couldn't find a setting. I also checked and found that this is not theme specific (whichever theme I select, this highlighting is shown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `Whitespace` bundle under the `Bundle Editor`; select it, then `Language Grammars`  disable `Trailing Whitespace` by unchecking `Enable this item`.

As the OP commented, you may have to restart Textmate for this to take effect.

[image: Textmate 2's bundle editor on the whitespace bundle -> Language Grammars -> Trailing Whitespace]

Comment: I had to restart Textmate for it to take effect, but it worked!